# Can I ask pep8 in python to parse a string instead of a file?

Tags: python, format, pep8, pep8-checker

```
import pep8

s = """
def a:
    pass

def b:
   pass

"""

pep8.StyleGuide().is_such_method_exists_for_string_?(s)
```

// and then, get out put as list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pep8

lines = """
def a:
    pass

def b:
   pass
"""

checker = pep8.Checker(
    lines=lines.strip().splitlines(),
    filename=None,
    show_source=True
)
result = checker.check_all()
```

Comment: Sorry, first time asking :P